# How can I determine where power enters my bathroom light circuit?

Tags: electrical, wiring, bathroom-fixtures

How do I determine if the power source is going right into the 3-gang box of switches, or directly to one of the fixtures (1 vanity light and 1 light/exhaust fan combo)?  What is the best way to install new light fixtures (say over the shower and/or bathtub), taking power from the light of the light/fan combo?

Essentially, we are looking to have the current switch that turns on the light of the light/fan fixture also turn on the new lights.  The other two switches will remain connected to their respective fixtures (the exhaust fan and the vanity lights).  Thanks!

Comment: If you're able to post clear photos of the cables and connections at each location we can probably help. Otherwise, get yourself an inexpensive multimeter and start investigating.

Comment: When saying over the tub / shower are you aware of the code requirements? Many folks place them at the edge because listed damp/ wet location ones are ugly. NEC 410.10.A & D

Answer (score 1):

OP seems to have done a scarper but for anyone else reading this:

The one sure way to find where the power enters a circuit is to completely disconnect each cable and drop a test load across its wires.

I detach the cables one at a time and re-connect each one before going on to the next. This saves having to mark everything first -- although it does involve a lot of running back and forth to the circuit breaker panel.

My favorite test load is a neon indicator lamp on a short piece of lamp cord with two insulated alligator clips. But almost any kind of lamp can be pressed into service.

Answer (score 0):

To find the source run, you will need to see how the switches are wired, or looking up in the ceiling. As for adding a light, permit will be needed, water safe light fixture, and just pull a wire from the existing fixture to your new hole and wire it up. Of course power off for this install.....